# Outlook Web Add-in not activating in Calendar edit mode

Tags: outlook, office365, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to write an Outlook web add-in to ask for additional information when creating a new appointment. At this point I'm able to open my add-in's pane when reading an appointment, but when I try to create or edit an appointment, this pane isn't visible. What do I have to do to have this be displayed when creating or edit an appointment? I tried different OfficeApp types and different types of ExtensionPoints.

My manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:...-->
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->
  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>...</Id>
  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>My Company</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Add-In" />
  <Description DefaultValue="My First Outlook Web Add-In" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.live.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->
  <Hosts>    
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>    
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MeetingRead.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>    
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="ReadOrEdit" />        
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="group1">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneShowLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneShowLabel" />
                    <Description resid="paneShowTooltipLong" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->         
        </DesktopFormFactor>        
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MessageRead.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Group label" />
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel" DefaultValue="Tab label" />
        <bt:String id="paneShowLabel" DefaultValue="Pane label" />
        <bt:String id="paneShowTooltipShort" DefaultValue="Open pane." />        
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneShowTooltipLong" DefaultValue="Look for any options in this element." />
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription"
                   DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

If you need additional files or informations, just ask.

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a Form element for type ItemEdit.  Try adding that inside FormSetting, similar to this:

```
<FormSetting>
  ...
  <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
    <DesktopSettings>
      <SourceLocation DefaultValue="your url" />
      <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
    </DesktopSettings>
  </Form> 
</FormSetting>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I'm able to open my plugin pane by clicking on "Add-Ins" and than selecting it. But is it possible to include it in the edit plane or immeditly opening the Add-In pane with my plugin selected?

Answer (score 1):

If you are under AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface, your button should be added to the ribbon on all appointments that YOU are the organizer. Adding a button under: AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface Adds a button when you are NOT the organizer (you would probably be an Attendee in that case).

Are you not seeing your button show up in the Ribbon? What Version of Outlook are you on? (or are you trying to do this in OWA?)

There is currently no way to open a pane by default when an item opens. This is a highly requested feature though.

Comment: Tim, it seems ItmeId is not available when editing an existing event (AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface). Is there a way to get ItemId in the edit mode? Thanks

Comment: Try using item.saveAsync(). 

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5